# Why do multiple plus operators parse?

Tags: javascript, parsing, operators

I don't understand why the following javascript parses; what's going on?

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
console.log(a + + + + + + + b);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

In addition, when it does parse I'd at least expect one of `a` or `b` to be incremented, but they are not.

### Output (Chrome):

```
0
0
0
```

### Output (Firefox):

```
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the increment way is with `a++`.

That you make here is to changing the sign of the number, but we know that `+` don't change the sign (opposite to `-`). So in this:

```
 console.log(a + + + + + + + b);
```

You are saying:

```
a + (+ (+ (+ (+ b) ) ) )
```

So you are not changing the sign nor incrementing the numbers. Check this:

```
 console.log(a++ + + + + + + + b);
```

You'll obtain an increment in `a` variable. Output:

```
 0
 1
 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has an unary plus operator, so this expression is essentially the same as

```
console.log(a + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ b)))))));
```

which is just, eventually, equivalent to

```
console.log(a + b);
```

Note that the increment operator, `++` (be it a prefix or postfix operator) cannot have a whitespace between the `+`s.

Comment: Makes sense, but if this is the case then why does the following output `-1`?  `var x = -1; console.log('' + + x)`

Comment: The above statement is mathematically true, it does not refer only to javascript.

Comment: If you see my answer, I explain it `That you make here is to changing the sign of the number, but we know that + don't change the sign (opposite to -).`